# LPCSTR has no 'long' and UINT_PTR has no pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, msdn

On this website: [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#LPCSTR)

the question of the topic arises.

LP stands for long pointer I presume - but there's no long.
UINT_PTR stands for unsigned int pointer I presume again - but there's no pointer.

Does someone know the background of this?

Comment: You questions are contradictory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Referring "*long pointers*" (`LP`-types):**

There where times (pre-Pentium) where you had [long and short pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation). And as the WINAPI already existed during those times, and today still tries to stay compatible to code of those days, the `LPsomething`-types survived.

**Referring `UINT_PTR`:**

That's an integer wide enough for holding the value of a pointer. The C11-Standard defines such a type as as follows:

> **7.20.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers**
>
> 1 The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid
>   pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
>   intptr_t
> ```
>
> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid
>   pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
>   uintptr_t
> ```
>
> These types are optional.

Comment: long pointers are from the 16-bit days, when you had segment:offset memory addressing. A long pointer (aka far pointer) included both segment and offset. A near pointer only included the offset into the segment. It was purely an Intel x86 architecture thing.

Answer (score 5):

`UINT_PTR` is not a pointer type. It is an unsigned integer type of sufficient width to store a pointer value (so its width depends on the target platform). It exists because `int` and `unsigned int` are not necessarily wide enough to hold a pointer (particularly on Windows for x64 where `int` is still 32 bits and pointers are 64 bits).

Comment: It's not just on x64 that int is 32 bits. It is on some platforms that long is still 32 bits, even though the platform has 64-bit integers (LLP64 systems), but that depends on the compiler/system, not on the CPU. See e.g. Linux vs MS Windows on the same platform.